# How to create a table using the INSERT INTO clause using linked servers in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I have a server called `GreatPlains` and I would like to create a new table (not already defined) using the `INSERT INTO` clause onto my local server's reporting database. We have a linked server set up for the `GreatPlains` server and our main production server.

Simplified version of current query:

```
SELECT *
INTO [local].[Reporting].[dbo].[NewTable]
FROM [linked].[Main].[dbo].[Orders]
```

I'm also getting the error:

> The object name 'local.Reporting.dbo.NewTable' contains more than the
>   maximum number of prefixes. The maximum is 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two mistakes in your query

1.`INTO` clause support maximum of 2 prefixes. You cannot include `SERVER NAME`

```
DATABASE_NAME.SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME
```

2.Unwanted `INSERT` ketword

So your query should be

```
SELECT *
INTO [Reporting].[dbo].[NewTable]
FROM [linked].[Main].[dbo].[Orders];
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you have an extra `insert`:

```
SELECT *
INTO [local].[Reporting].[dbo].[NewTable]
FROM [linked].[Main].[dbo].[Orders];
```

If the table is already defined and has the same columns in the same order, then you can do:

```
INSERT INTO [local].[Reporting].[dbo].[NewTable]
    SELECT *
    FROM [linked].[Main].[dbo].[Orders];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the script in your local server and table already exists in the database,Use the below script.

```
 USE [Reporting]
 GO

 INSERT INTO [dbo].[NewTable]
 SELECT *
 FROM [linked].[Main].[dbo].[Orders]
```

If you don't have the table in your database,use the below script.

```
USE [Reporting]
GO

 SELECT *
  INTO dbo.[NewTable]
 FROM [linked].[Main].[dbo].[Orders]
```